# Can a PYQT signal be suppressed / mutually updating fields in PYQT

Tags: python, pyqt5, signals

I'm building a user interface in PYQT, and I've run into a bit of a problem. I want to allow the user to arm (start) a process after a delay, and I want to let them set that delay either by selecting a time for the device to arm, or a delay in hours/minutes/seconds from the time they click the button. That much I can do.

The functionality is for important and highly time-sensitive tests, so for maximum clarity, I also display the current time and use a timer to update it every second.

My issue is, if the user sets the delay using the 'arm time' field, I want to continuously update the 'arm delay' field to show how long remains until that time. Likewise, if the user sets the delay using the 'arm delay' field, I want to continuously update the 'arm time' field to show when the device would arm if they were at that moment to start a delay of the specified duration. My question is, how can I detect which field the user most recently edited, without the program getting confused by the automated changes in the other field?

The DateTimeChanged signal seems like the obvious tool here, but I don't know how to separate the automated changes from user inputs - is there a way to suppress this signal when the field is changed by the machine, or is there another convenient way to recognize when user input has changed a field?

Comment: See [QSignalBlocker](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html): `with QSignalBlocker(someWidget): someWidget.setValue(xyz)`.

Answer (score 0):

Self-answering because @musicamante pointed me in the right direction and I was able to figure it out. The goal (suppressing signals from specific objects at specific points in code execution) can be elegantly accomplished using python's with statement and QT's QSignalBlocker class as follows:

```
def functionThatDoesntSignal()
    with QSignalBlocker(myWidget):
        myWidget.doStuff()  # Won't send signals
    myWidget.doStuff()  # Will send signals now that the signal blocker is out of scope
```

Note that the widget passed to the QSignalBLocker constructor must be the widget which would emit the signal; in my case, the DateTimeEdit that the code is updating.